# What's the integration of 1/sinax?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried it by using the substitution method (u = 2x) but the constant 'a' makes me reach a dead end when I divide the integrals to two parts. Now I've seen many videos on how to handle 1/sinx, but I can't reach a solution when the angle has another constant in it. What am I missing?

Comment: try $u=ax$ instead.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{\sin(ax)} \,\mathrm{d}x
    &= \int \csc(ax) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= \frac{ -\ln | \csc(ax) + \cot(ax)|}{a} + C  \text{.}
\end{align*}
If you are familiar with the antiderivative of cosecant, \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \cot x &= -\csc^2 x  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \csc x &= -\csc x \cot x
\end{align*}
so
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (\csc x + \cot x) = \csc x(\csc x + \cot x)  $$
Then
$$  - \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (\csc x + \cot x)}{(\csc x + \cot x)} = \csc x  \text{.}  $$
Antidifferentiating both sides and recognizing the left-hand side is a logarithm produces the result used above.

Comment: this is so cool! thanks a ton